# How to runn external DAG as part of my DAG?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to Airflow and I'm trying to run an external DAG (developed and owned by another team), as part of my DAG flow.

I was looking at SubDagOperator, but it seems that for some reason it enforces the name of the subdag to be . which I cannot do as the child dag is owned by a different team.

here is my code sample:

```
parent_dag = DAG(
dag_id='parent_dag', default_args=args,
schedule_interval=None)

external_dag = SubDagOperator(
subdag=another_teams_dag,
task_id='external_dag',
dag=parent_dag,
trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
)
```

and the other team's dag is defined like this:

```
another_teams_dag = DAG(
dag_id='another_teams_dag', default_args=args,
schedule_interval=None)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> The subdag's dag_id should have the form
>   '{parent_dag_id}.{this_task_id}'. Expected 'parent_dag.external_dag';
>   received 'another_teams_dag'.

Any ideas?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TriggerDagRunOperator`

More info: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator

Example:

**Dag that triggers**: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py

**Dag that is triggered**: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py

For your case, you can use something like:

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='external_dag',
                                trigger_dag_id="another_teams_dag",
                                dag=dag)
```